# Does C# MemoryCache persist over IIS Application Pool Idle Timeout

Tags: asp.net, caching

As per question, if I set a MemoryCache with CacheItemPolicy expiration date to be 1 day, does it survive the Application Pool Idle Timeout of 20 minutes (provided the application pool itself is not recycled - which can be quite long)?